# Tex Editor in Ubuntu that can show the source file when (double) click to the PDF file

Tags: editors

My question is just in the title. My tex source is broken into > 20 files (only a few are written by me). Is there a editor in Ubuntu that allow me to quickly locate the source file when reading the PDF?

Comment: If you use texstudio with synctex, you can right click in the pdf and chose "go to source". This will open the corresponding file at the correct position.

Comment: @samcarter: Thanks, I just installed texstudio, but I don't know how to set TEXINPUTS for it

Comment: @samcarter I just figured out that it's OK to compile using command line, although setting TEXTINPUTS is more convenient. Could you please turn your comment to an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks so much.

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables how to set system variables also for applications, or https://superuser.com/a/398881/383391

Comment: @samcarter Yes, I set it in my .bashrc file, and I can run it OK with pdflatex from command line. However, when I run the command from TexStudio, it says it couldn't find ***.sty (which is in my TEXINPUTS)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have ubuntu, so I cannot test. superuser.com or askubuntu.com might be good places to ask about this.

Comment: As  a workaround, you could open texstudio from command line, this way it should have the environment variables from your terminal.

Comment: @samcarter thanks, open texstudio from command line works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is TeXStudio used together with `synctex` enabled. Probably most other editors which support synctex will behave similarly.

On right click in the pdf, you will see context menu with "Go to Source"

[image]

Texstudio will then open the file and jump to the relevant position in the source.